# Printing Stack Overflow articles

Tags: discussion, printing, stack-overflow

I've noticed on a number of occasions that code displayed on Stack Overflow often requires scrolling in order to view it. While not a big deal when viewing questions and answers, it can be troublesome when I want to print the article out.

Am I missing something simple? I've already tried adjusting my browser's font size, but that scales the whole page.

Comment: Its a kind of feature request what you are asking .Like the way we have share edit retag flag and ther links below the posting we can have a print button which prints with who has posted and hyperlink to his profile at stackoverflow ,

Comment: Nothing built in, but [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/) still work.